# .htaccess redirect parameter to sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect pages like

> www.domain.com/cat/listen?i=Name

to

> www.domain.com/main/cat/subcat/name

I have tried these before but didn't help.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} i=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/cat/listen(.*) /main/cat/subcat/%1
```

AND

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?main/cat/subcat/([^/d]+)/?$ cat/listen?i=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm suspicious about the uppercase letter in the old sites parameter but new site using wordpress so it shouldn't the source of problem, I guess.

I've searched and tried different methods too, but can't figured it out. I think I'm missing something really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably the **leading slash** in RewriteRule pattern.  leading slash is not required in RewriteRule on htaccess context.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} i=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat/listen(.*) /main/cat/subcat/%1? [R,L]
```

Empty question mark at the end of the target url is importent as it discards the orignal query strings.